# Fun with particles - making a sentence that uses as many as 'em

Tags: particles, puns

Let's have some fun with particles! Create a sentence using as many particles as you can. Rules:

1. The sentence can combine any number of clauses or ideas but it must be meaningful (i.e. no gibberish) and should be using standard Japanese (i.e. no slang).
2. Each entry will be given a score based on how many unique usages of particles; 1 point per particle. No point is given to repeated particles unless they are used for different roles, for example using one から for denoting reason and another for denoting origin of movement give 2 points. Please count the score and include it in your entry (also recommended if you can bold/highlight the particles that you count).
3. Compound particles (では, でも, のに etc) are considered different particles from their atomic particles as long as their roles are clearly distinct from the latter. A counter-example would be something like "X からの Y" where the からの is simply から + の particles.
4. Sentences that simply list down all the particles do not qualify as "meaningful".
5. One entry per answer, please.

NB: Dear moderators, please make this into CW. On whether this kind of question is allowable or not, please discuss in [this meta discussion](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/should-for-fun-game-trivia-questions-be-allowed). To all, let's refrain from voting up/down in here until this becomes CW, just to not disturb the rep points ;)

Comment: Hum, how about a 100 pages long sentence? I suggest you divide the number of particules by the number of morae, so that you can somehow normalize results.

Comment: Can we agree on a list of particles? Ex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_particles#List_of_particles

Comment: @Axioplase If that 100 pages long sentence uses up all the particles in existence then I don't have any problem with giving it the maximum score. Repeated particles are not counted anyway.

Comment: @repecmps Good idea. Does that wikipedia article contain the most exhaustive list of particles? Any better list out there?

Comment: Sorry people, this is not even remotely "practical, answerable, and based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: @Amanda S: You don't even need to vote? Have you even participated in the meta discussion? http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/373/should-for-fun-game-trivia-questions-be-allowed

Comment: Post made CW, but you may need to wait one more reopen vote.

Comment: If it doesn't reopen, does it mean I win by default? :)

Comment: This has been reopened! Thanks to the voters :)

Comment: are けど, けれど, けれども three distinct particles?

Comment: For future reference, if you would like a post made community wiki, you should flag it for moderator attention.  I think it's a little counter-intuitive to have to flag you own post, but it makes it easy for a moderator to find, instead of relying on us to read your post down to its postscript. :o)

Comment: @Amanda: Noted. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

**25**

(Some repeated particles have different roles.)

I added some unnecessary　「、」　to make the sentence a little more readable.

> 猫**や**犬**などと**言う**のは**「ペット」と英語**で**呼ばれる**けど**、僕**の**家**に**はそんな動物**が**いない**ので**、**なんか**寂しい感じがする**が**、お父さんは僕**に**「毎日家**から**出て、学校**へ**行く**なら**、友達**と**遊べることができる**のさ**」と言われて、キャンディー**を**もらう**と**、すぐ嬉しくなる**わよね**。

や,
など,
と,
の,
は,
で,
けど,
の,
に,
が,
ので,
なんか,
が,
に,
から,
へ,
なら,
と,
の、
さ,
を,
と,
わ,
よ,
ね

Obviously this can be longer but my imagination is limited.

Comment: Nice sentence. I love the story! Would be great if you can bold/highlight the particles you counted, got confused with the many と.

Comment: I tried highlighting at first but there's some kind of bug. http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/120/issues-with-bolding I'll try the <b> solution

Comment: Is こと a particle?

Comment: no :D I got confused with "mono" listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_particles#List_of_particles removed.

Answer (score 1):

"「よ、ね、な、で、に、へ、が、は、と、から、の、では、でも、のに、ので」は助詞です。"
That could be even longer, but you get the point that it's going to be difficult to beat the concept :)

Comment: This is cheating. Maybe I'll add another rule to specifically disqualify sentences like this.

Comment: @Lukman: changing the rules after you lost is cheating! :) And that could even be a perfectly valid sentence that may be found in a grammar book or a wikipedia page at the "particles" page!

Comment: Well, I'm calling it "fixing the security hole". People do it all the time ;)